# a released named ws-dev is in use, cannot re-use a name that is still in use

Tags: kubernetes-helm

UPGRADE FAILED: a released named ws-dev is in use, cannot re-use a name that is still in use ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Using $ helm version --client
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0",  GitTreeState:"clean"}

and kubectl version --client=true
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+",...}

Comment: Helm version 2 is really old, and unsupported at this point.  If you can't upgrade to Helm 3 (and admittedly the production migration looks intimidating) can you at least use the most recent Helm 2.17.0 and the corresponding Tiller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear.

You cannot deploy a project repeatedly with the same name.

You can view the deployed projects through `helm list`.

For those who need to update the deployment, you can use the `helm update xxx .`command.

Or use the method of deleting (`helm uninstall xxx`) and then redeploying (`helm install xxx .`).

Comment: (On Helm 2, you probably need `helm delete --purge ws-dev`, I don't think `helm uninstall` existed yet.)